# Javascript (Floating-Point Question): is there any reliable way to convert a fraction to a decimal AND THEN BACK AGAIN?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, data-conversion, fractions

Say I have a very simple fraction *(for the purposes of this question, presuppose all cases discussed will be `0 < [VALUE] < 1`; that is: nothing like `8 7/16` or `1.625`)*:

My starting fraction:

> `someFraction = '1/3'; // result: STRING value containing "1/3"`.

Okay easy enough to convert that to a decimal:

> `correspondingDecimal = eval(someFraction); // result: FLOAT value containing 0.3333333333333333`

*(yes, yes, "evils of `eval` and all that. Work with me here; this is an example)*

Now say I wanted it BACK again to `"1/3"`. If this were `1/4 (0.25)`, no problem:

We'd want a simple greatest common denominator function (to reduce the results to manageability), say

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator){ 
    let getGCD = (a,b) => b ? getGCD(b, a%b) : a; 
    gcd = getGCD(numerator,denominator); 
    return (numerator/gcd) + '/' + (denominator/gcd); 
}
```

...and then we can just grab out the decimal portion of our test string:

```
let justDecimalPart = ('' + 0.25).slice(2);
```

and multiply by its length power to get our numerator and our denominator to reduce:

```
let commonFactor = Math.pow(10,justDecimalPart.length); // Result: 100
//                     = 25                 = 100
reduce((justDecimalPart * commonFactor), commonFactor); // Result: 1/4
```

... capital! That worked out fine!

EDIT: On a whim, I tried that same reduce function on the decimal values without multiplying them at all (`reduce(0.25,1); // result: "1/4"`). Sorry; brain-fart. Ignore the exponent bit above ☺️

...But `1/3` is a *repeating* decimal. If we run the same steps through, we wind up with `3333333333333333/10000000000000000` (`((1/3) * 1e16) + '/' + 1e16`).  It's even worse with something like `17/29`.

Is there any way to arrive BACK at `"1/3"` after taking the plunge from `1/3`?

EDIT: I'm not trying to get to an infinite precision, just to a manageable one, preferably through throttling/limiting decimal lengths and then rounding/simplifying the result.

Use-case example here: I'm working on a carpentry calculator. 25mm, expressed in US Common units (to a precision of 3 decimal places) is identical to 63/64. I can only seem to arrive at 125/128.

```
(25/25.4).toPrecision(3) = 0.984
(63/64).toPrecision(3) = 0.984
```

Comment: no there isn't, and it has nothing to do with javascript, that's just math. you cannot accurately express 1/3 as a decimal, you can only express an estimation of it.

Comment: No, and I get that. I was hoping someone might have a neat trick for offsetting/reducing the numbers to arrive at the same point. I'm not trying to make this work to infinite precision, just to 1/128 or so.

Comment: You say it yourself in your question, you wind up with `3333333333333333/10000000000000000`. The only way would be to limit the size of the numerator/denominator in the conversion. This would reduce the accuracy of the conversion back from decimal to fraction, but makes it more likely that your result is close to what you want.

Comment: Right, and that's what I'm hoping to arrive at here, and why the included reduce function maintains a separate numerator and denominator. If I take a value `.toPrecision(3)` it, say, and then round the conversion before reducing...

Comment: You just found (a well-known fact) that some rational has no finite decimal expansion. So if you work with such expansions you cannot express all the rationals. The way around this is to never perform the expansion in the first place (i.e. the division). That's why we need "libraries" for rationals in the first place (that allow us to express 0.33... as 1/3, for example), otherwise, we'd just use the floating-point numbers and let the compile figure it out the floating-point value of the expression 1/3 or similar.

Comment: Again: I grasp that. I'm looking for a "fudge-factor" that, even at the expense of some degree of precision, allows me to arrive back at a similar starting point. Please see edits in original post.

Comment: Did you try `Math.floor``

Comment: @bluejayke actually, Math.round did it for me. I'd been trying to multiply the `0.984` by 128000 (1/128" precision, times 1000 to accommodate the decimal bit, trusting in the reduction). Turns out that if I multiply by that same 128, then round the value, THEN apply the reduction, I'm seeing the results I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I was leaving out a step in my conversion; I wasn't rounding the result of the decimal multiplied against the denominator:

```
decimalValue = (63 / 64).toPrecision(3); // Result: 0.984
denominator = 128; 
numerator = decimalValue * denominator; // Result: 125.952
numerator = Math.round(numerator); // Result: 126
reduce(numerator, denominator); // Result: 63/64
```